# Is possible create variables to use on tiny mce?

Tags: variables, tinymce

How can I use php variables like `$username` or `$date_event` on tinymce? I'm looking for it is possible do that in **tinymce.init**

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved.
I used this plugin https://github.com/bubobox/tinymce-variable

Comment: https://github.com/ziktar/tinymce-variable or https://github.com/ronaldojf/tinymce-variable for more up to date.